# PartSim Simulation for Transient Step-Response (RC Circuit) Has Unexpected Result

Tags: simulation, step-response, partsim

this is my first question on stackexchange, so forgive me if my format is not ideal.

I am currently trying to simulate a RC circuit, and producing a step-response graph that should look similar to this:

[image: What it should look like]

However, with my circuit set up like this:
[image: My circuit diagram]

I am not getting the transient response I expected, as they stay constant, even though I am setting the initial condition of my capacitor to be 0 V.

[image: Stays constant at 2.5V]

From what I'm understanding, it seems like it is reading it to be a steady state response instead of the step response that I am looking for, but I thought that was taken care of because I set the initial condition of the capacitor's voltage to be 0. Can anyone try to send me in the right direction? I have been stuck at this for quite a while now.

Comment: Did you check the use initial conditions of components checkbox in the simulator options?

Comment: I found what you meant and it fixed my problem. Thank you!